# How to perform phonetic matching/query for multivalued string field

Tags: solr

I want to query a list of terms indexed and stored in multivalued string field via `Term Component`. The term component can support exact matching and regex based fuzzy matching.

However, Is any way I can configure schema to do phonetic matching/query? I understand that I can configure `solr.PhoneticFilterFactory` for a `solr.TextField`. However, doing a full text query will return all the matched document rather than a list of strings.

Any idea?